# RestTemplate gives 400 Bad Request Error on a Get Request

Tags: spring, rest, http, resttemplate, dbpedia

When I try to make a get request with Spring's RestTemplate, it gives 400 BAD Request. I can call the same url from javascript successfully with the headers below :

[image]

But the code below does not work. What might be the cause?

```
public Entity getEntityByUri(String uri) {
        String req = "http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?query=DESCRIBE%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Concept_learning%3E&format=application%2Fjson-ld";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));

    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    new RestTemplate().exchange(req, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, Map.class);

    Entity entity = new Entity();
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: too less information. Where is your code which is accepting this rest request. Recheck the url ou have put. is this a real url?

Comment: Yes of course, you can try it on your browser. It also runs correctly when called directly via HttpUrlConnection or IOUtils.read(). This is the code that accepts the request. The problem is with the inner workings of Springs RestTemplate, I thought that it may be the headers first and changed as it can be seen on the question, but still the problem persists. There is not much information to give, this code runs correctly with other urls as well, and this url response correctly when called from other clients.

Comment: @cuneytyvz are you aware that Rest Template encodes the URL unless you use the constructor method specific for URI?

Comment: @Coder So I should decode the URI and try again?

Comment: @cuneytyvz you don't have to decode. Instead of using URL use an URI. Then rest template won't try to encode it again

Answer (score 2):

Your url is already encoded. Popular browsers such as Chrome are capable of understanding and responding appropriately. However, it's not the same case with `RestTemplate`.

I had to decode your uri [here](https://www.urldecoder.org/) and the decoded uri is `DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Concept_learning>`

Having checked the browser console, I got to know you have two query strings passed in the url, they are `query` and `format` holding values `DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Concept_learning>` and `application/json-ld` respectively.

I assume `Entity` class is the pojo class of json response.

Have created **Entity** as from your json response:

```
public class Entity {

    private String value;

    private String type;

    // getters and setters omitted for brevity

}
```

Finally in your `getEntityByUri` method have got the instance of `UriComponentsBuilder` which handles uri encoding and query params.

To sum up, your `getEntityByUri` looks below.

```
public HttpEntity<Entity> getEntityByUri() {
        String req = "http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql";

        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(req)
                .queryParam("query",
                        "DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Concept_learning>")
                .queryParam("format", "application/json-ld");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        return new RestTemplate().exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, Entity.class);
    }
```

The above method didn't throw `HTTP400` as the required query params have been passed in `builder` object.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Anyone getting same error make sure your URL is decoded means no percent symbols in url (if space in param values).

This worked for me

```
    try {
        requestURL = URLDecoder.decode("http://api.com?p=1&groups=3212&affected-since=2019-06-06T14%3A11%3A14.880&detail=full&after-id=43536", "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));

generates a malformed "Accept" header field? (FWIW, why do you send it at all???)